# What is vectors straddle a plane mean?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, partial-differential-equations, vectors, hyperbolic-geometry, vector-fields

There is a condition in a paper, saying that two vectors straddle a plane. How can we transfer this condition to a equation? Because I have another 5 equations and need this one to solve 6 unknowns. Thanks.
Here is a figure for it. The vector $ \alpha $ and $\beta $ straddle the reference plane. Assume we know the function of the plane.

[image: the vector \alpha and \beta straddle the reference plane]

Comment: More context would help - how about copying for us the entire paragraph where this phrase occurs?

Comment: Also, my initial guess would be that "straddle" means "linearly span".

Comment: Maybe this condition is just mean that the intersection of the two vectors is located in the reference plane, is this make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that it means that if $N$ is the normal vector to the plane, then the dot products $N \cdot \alpha$ and $N \cdot \beta$ have opposite signs. In other words, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are on opposite sides of the plane.

Comment: Good point, other words, the angles of  $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with the plane are the same. It really make sense! Thanks.